# Paper about this secure P2P idea?

Tags: encryption, reference-request

Two or three years ago, I was reading something interesting, but then I lost the paper. The paper described building secure and fast P2P networks (not like tor or I2P).
Unfortunately, I only remember some parts of the protocol/algorithm:

- Peer logical address not equal to physical address, actually logical address is public encryption key.
- When sending message through peer tunnel we encrypt by all public keys of peers in tunnel consequentially $(key_0(key_1(...key_N(data))))$
- Unable to detect actual sender and receiver by analysing packet data.
- Also, sender cannot find receiver and receiver cannot find sender of message.
- Unable to detect if next peer is last or previous is first in peer sequence.

What paper was this?

Comment: This does not seem to be too different from I2P.

Comment: But it differs in main parts: it is faster and more secure.

Comment: It may very well be. On the other hand, I don't really see how you can be so sure about that considering you no longer have the paper. What I meant with my comment was really that what you describe in your question isn't very different from I2P.